# In SSTables, why is it possible to group records and compress them?

Tags: data-structures, distributed-systems, databases, storage, information-retrieval

I am currently reading 'Designing Data Intensive Applications' by Kleppman. In the SSTables and LSM Trees section, it is mentioned that one of the advantage of SSTables is:

"Since read requests need to scan over several key-value pairs in the requested range anyway, it is possible to group those records into a block and compress it before writing it to disk (indicated by the shaded area in Figure 3-5). Each entry of the sparse in-memory index then points at the start of a compressed block. Besides saving disk space, compression also reduces the I/O bandwidth use."

I was wondering why compression is not possible in simple log based records. And, if compression is possible in this case, will the read operation be slightly costly due to decompression at reading time.